# Initialization of Extended class without too much overhead?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am getting object of a class AAA from somewhere and I want to add more information in that object. So, I am creating a new class BBB which is derived from AAA. The class BBB has additional field dictionary. I am populating this dictionary in derived class constructor which is taking the Class AAA object and array of item which I want to use as keys of dictionary and values of this dictionary are elements of a field of object of class AAA. I tried to create similar scenario in blow example code:

```
void Main(){    
     A obj = new A () ;
     obj.prop1 =  new int [] {5 ,10, 15}   ;
     obj.prop2 =  "Hello" ;
     obj.prop3 = "World" ;
//   obj.Dump () ;
     B obj2 = new B (new int [] {1,2,3}, obj)  ;     
//   obj2.Dump () ;

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class A {
    public int [] prop1 ;
    public string prop2 ;
    public string prop3 ;
}

public class B : A {
    public Dictionary <int, int> prop4 ;
    public B (int [] keys, A a) {
    prop4 = new Dictionary <int, int> () ;
        if (keys.Length == a.prop1.Length ) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < keys.Length ; i++ ) {
                prop4.Add (keys[i], a.prop1[i]) ;
            }
            // is there a way to obsolete below lines of code???
            this.prop1 = a.prop1 ; 
            this.prop2 = a.prop2 ;
            this.prop3 = a.prop3 ;
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception ("something wrong") ;
        }           
    }
}
```

In derived class constructor, I am filling the properties manually and I do not want to do it. Is there another way to do it. I have more than 20 properties in my actual class.

Comment: Can you modify `A`? Does the real `A` have a constructor (apart from the parameterless one).

Answer (score 1):

Those lines are managing the properties of A, so they belong in A.  I've added a protected copy constructor and used constructor chaining to solve your issue:

```
public class A
{
  public int [] prop1 ;
  public string prop2 ;
  public string prop3 ;

  public A() {}

  protected A(A a)  //copy constructor
  {
    this.prop1 = a.prop1 ;  //review: should this reference be copied, or a new copy made?
    this.prop2 = a.prop2 ;
    this.prop3 = a.prop3 ;
  }
}

public class B : A
{
  public Dictionary <int, int> prop4 ;

  public B (int [] keys, A a) : base(a)  //constructor chaining
  {
    prop4 = new Dictionary <int, int> () ;
    if (keys.Length == a.prop1.Length )
    {
      for (int i = 0 ; i < keys.Length ; i++ )
      {
        prop4.Add (keys[i], a.prop1[i]) ;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Exception ("something wrong") ;
    }           
  }
}
```